# Show $\sin\left(2\pi\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^{n}} \right)=\frac{(-1)^{n}\pi}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n^2}\right) $

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I would like to prove the following:

$$\sin\left(2\pi\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^{n}} \right)=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}\pi}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^2}\right). $$

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
\sin\left(2\pi\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^{n}} \right)&=\sin\left(2\pi\sqrt{n^2\left(1+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2}\right)} \right) \\
&= \sin\left(2\pi\ n\left(1+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{2}} \right)  \\
&=\sin\left(2\pi\ n\left(1+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{2n^2}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{4}}\right)\right) \right) \\
&=\sin\left(2\pi\ n+\dfrac{(-1)^{n}\pi}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)  \\
&=(-1)^{2n}\sin\left(\dfrac{(-1)^{n}\pi}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right)  \\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}\pi}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{3}}\right).  \\
\end{align*}

I got $\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{3}}\right) $ instead of $\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right). $
  Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct. Your answer is more accurate.

Comment: so they made a mistake ?

Comment: @Educ: You skipped some justifications at the last step, but it's not a mistake to give a correct statement even though a stronger statement holds. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you have is quite correct and is a more powerful statement than the one they provided. You skipped some details at the end. You in fact need to use $\sin x = x + O(x^3)$ at the last step, and I'm guessing that the original author used only $\sin x = x + O(x^2)$. One gets the stronger result here by using the *second-order* Taylor polynomial of $\sin$ at $0$.

Comment: as i know $$\sin x = x +-\dfrac{x^{3}}{3}+o(x^3)\implies \sin x = x + O(x^3) $$ and where that come from $\sin x = x + O(x^2) $

Comment: In general, if one considers just the *first*-order Taylor polynomial for $\sin$, rather than second, one gets the $O(x^2)$ error estimate. ... I still say that if you're writing a careful explanation, you should include this observation as justification for the last step.

Comment: @Educ Since, as $x \to 0$, $O(x^3)=O(x^2)$ we can't say there is a mistake. As explained by Ted Shifrin above.

Comment: but please could you tell me why the author always prefer order $2$